# Issue with function definition for Write and Call Some Simple Functions

Tags: python

I know you guys are not here to do my homework for me, but I just don't have enough python program knowledge to resolve the assignment.  I tried, but it doesn't seems working.  Can you please help me out?  Below is the assignment.

Assignment instruction:

Page 1 of 3

Instructions

> Examine the starter code in the code editor window and understand what it is doing.
>
> Content of the exercise.py file is below which is in the editor window.
>
> ```
> x = 3 
> y = 4 
> if x < y: 
>     min_xy = x 
> else: 
>     min_xy = y 
> print(min_xy) 
>
> a = 12.3 
> b = 13.7 
>
> if a < b: 
>     min_ab = a 
> else: 
>     min_ab = b 
> print(min_ab) 
>
> w = -3.9 
> z = -4.7 
> if w < z: 
>     min_wz = w 
> else: 
>     min_wz = z 
>
> print(min_wz)
> ```
>
> Instructions
>
> Now we want to write a Python function that carries out this repeated
> operation, so that we can just write it once and call it repeatedly.
>
> In the code editor, at the top of the file before the existing code,
> write a function named find_min that takes two inputs and returns the
> lesser of the two. Remember to use the def keyword to start the
> definition of a new function, indent the body of the function under
> the def line, and return the result at the end.
>
> Start the ipython interpreter by typing ipython at the command prompt.
> Run the exercise in the interpreter (%run exercise.py): you should see
> some variables printed out from the starter code. Type %who to see
> that the interpreter also knows about your new function find_min. Test
> out your new function interactively within the interpreter, with some
> input values of your choosing.
>
> Now we want to reorganize exercise.py so that it does the same thing
> as before, except more efficiently by using your new find_min
> function.
>
> Replace the appropriate blocks of code with new code that accomplishes
> the same thing by calling your find_min function. Do not replace the
> variables or change their values.
>
> For example, one such operation will call find_min with the variables
> x (with x having a value of 3) and y (with y having a value of 4) as
> arguments and assign the returned value to the new variable min_xy.
>
> Verify that your new code runs and produces the same results as the
> original code.

My function definition is below.

```
def find_min(x, y): 
    if x < y: 
        return x 
    else: 
        return y 

    min_xy = find_min(3, 4) 

    print(min_xy)
```

I am getting the following errors:

Tests that failed:

! Call function find_min to find the lesser of x (x has a value of 3) and y (y has a value of 4) and assign returned value to min_xy
make sure x and y are defined create min_xy

! Call function find_min to find the lesser of a (a has a value of 12.3) and b (b has a value of 13.7) and assign returned value to min_ab
make sure a and b are defined create variable min_ab

! Call function find_min to find the lesser of w (w has a value of -3.9) and z (z has a value of -4.7) and assign returned value to min_wz
make sure w and z are defined create min_wz

> Page 2 of 3
>
> Instructions
>
> The code editor should contain your find_min function. We are free to
> define more than one function in our code. In the code editor, write a
> second function called find_max that takes two inputs and returns the
> greater of the two. Do Not Delete the Existing Code in the Code
> Editor.
>
> Use your new function to find the greater of x (x has a value of 3)
> and y (y has a value of 4) and assign it to the variable max_xy.
>
> Thanks in advance,

Marie

Comment: The call to the function should not be indented inside the function.

Comment: Thank you Barmar.  Got it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the call of the function out of the function definition.

```
def find_min(x, y): 
    if x < y: 
        return x 
    else: 
        return y 

min_xy = find_min(3, 4) 
print(min_xy)
```